# Displaying data from two different tables with values that are different lengths

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to display data from two different tables (without a common column), but the only problem is that the column I try to join the two tables on are different lengths. One is mostly 3 characters in length and the other is 2 characters in length. So in the cases where both columns have values that are the same length, it can output without a NULL (ex. UK and UK), but in scenarios of 3:2 (ex. USA and US) it doesn't. I'm using SQL Developer. Here's what I've figured out so far.

```
SELECT CUST_NO, CNAME, COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_CD, COUNTRY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMERS
RIGHT OUTER JOIN COUNTRIES ON CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY_CD = COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID LIKE '_%_%';
```

Sample data from Customers:

```
CUST_NO: 1053

CNAME: Sportwaren G.m.b.H 3

STATUS: A

CUST_TYPE: SPORTS: Sports Chain

COUNTRY_CD: GER

BRANCH_CD: FRNK
```

Sample Data from Countries:

```
COUNTRY_ID: AR

COUNTRY_NAME: ARGENTINA

REGION_ID: 2
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: I couldn't copy/paste it straight from SQL, so I just typed up one line from both tables along with the column names.

Comment: ok great it seems to me that COUNTRY_ID should be equal to COUNTRY_CD. If not then is a data cleansing issue

Comment: COUNTRY_ID does equal COUNTRY_CD, but only in cases where both rows have the same length, so something like USA in one column and US in another will render both rows null when displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cust_no
     , cname
     , country_id
     , country_cd
     , country_name
  FROM customers
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN countries ON SUBSTR (customers.country_cd, 1, 2) = SUBSTR (countries.country_id, 1, 2)
```